# Trouble implementing a custom MRUSplitButton in the ribbon

Tags: ribbon, custom-actions

In a publishing site, I would like to extend the ribbon to quickly set/unset a specific audience.

Basically, the user should be able , with a single click, to add or remove a specific audience (the audience has technical meaning elsewhere in the app).

I would like to provide a button in the ribbon similar to the "publish" button. What I mean is that the button should have different icon and meaning depending on the context:

- The state is undetermined yet --> grayed icon
- The audience is set --> icon and text to remove the audience,
- The audience is not set --> icon and text to add the audience,

When looking at the native publish command, I can see this is implemented using a `MRUSplitButton` with a button for each state, while others are disabled.

I'm trying to mimic this behavior. I build a custom page component, but this is not working as expected:

- the `getGlobalCommands` method is fired. In this method I provide my two commands.
- however, the `canHandleCommand` method is never fired.
- The whole split button is grayed. the icon and the arrow to drop down the menu are both grayed.

**What is wrong?**

Here is my code:

## elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
          <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.MyAudienceSetter.LargeRow">
            <Layout Title="MyAudienceSetterOneLarge"
                    LayoutTitle="MyAudienceSetterOneLarge">
              <OverflowSection TemplateAlias="OneRow1" DisplayMode="Large" Type="OneRow"/>
            </Layout>
          </GroupTemplate>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.Scaling._children">
          <MaxSize
            Id="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.MaxSize"
            Sequence="15"
            GroupId="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter"
            Size="MyAudienceSetterOneLarge" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.Groups._children">
          <Group
            Id="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter"
            Sequence="15"
            Description="Used to demo adding a group"
            Title="Promotion d'acutalité"
            Template="Ribbon.Templates.MyAudienceSetter.LargeRow">
            <Controls Id="MyProject.Ribbon.Controls">
              <MRUSplitButton
                Id="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.MyAudienceSetter"
                Sequence="10"
                Alt="$Resources:core,ButPublish;"
                InitialItem="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Menu.Promote.Promote"
                MenuAlt="$Resources:core,ButPublish;"
                TemplateAlias="OneRow1"
              >
                <Menu Id="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Menu">
                  <MenuSection Id="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Menu.Promote"
                               Sequence="10"
                               DisplayMode="Menu32">
                    <Controls Id="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Menu.Promote.Controls">
                      <Button
                        Id="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Menu.Promote.Promote"
                        MenuItemId="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Menu.Promote.Promote"
                        Sequence="10"
                        Alt="$Resources:core,ButPublish;"
                        Command="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Promote"
                        Image16by16="/_layouts/15/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png?rev=23"
                        Image16by16Top="-271"
                        Image16by16Left="-163"
                        Image32by32="/_layouts/15/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=23"
                        Image32by32Top="-341"
                        Image32by32Left="-375"
                        LabelText="$Resources:core,ButPublish;"
                        ToolTipTitle="$Resources:core,ButPublish;"
                        ToolTipDescription="$Resources:core,cui_STT_ButPublish_page;"
                        />
                      <Button
                        Id="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Menu.Promote.Demote"
                        MenuItemId="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Menu.Promote.Demote"
                        Sequence="20"
                        Alt="$Resources:core,ButSubmitForApproval;"
                        Command="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Demote"
                        Image16by16="/_layouts/15/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png?rev=23"
                        Image16by16Top="-37"
                        Image16by16Left="-133"
                        Image32by32="/_layouts/15/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=23"
                        Image32by32Top="-477"
                        Image32by32Left="-171"
                        LabelText="$Resources:core,ButSubmitForApprovalLabelText;"
                        ToolTipTitle="$Resources:core,ButSubmitForApproval;"
                        ToolTipDescription="$Resources:core,cui_STT_ButSubmitForApproval;"
                        />
                    </Controls>
                  </MenuSection>
                </Menu>
              </MRUSplitButton>
            </Controls>
          </Group>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>

    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>

  <CustomAction ScriptSrc="~SiteCollection/_layouts/15/MyProject/MyProject.MyAudienceSetter.loader.js"
                Location="ScriptLink"
                Sequence="1000" />

</Elements>
```

## MyAudienceSetter.js

```
Type.registerNamespace('MyProject');

MyProject.MyAudienceSetter = function () {
    MyProject.MyAudienceSetter.initializeBase(this);
}

MyProject.MyAudienceSetter.initialize = function () {
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Function.createDelegate(null, MyProject.MyAudienceSetter.initializePageComponent), 'SP.Ribbon.js');
}

MyProject.MyAudienceSetter.initializePageComponent = function () {
    var ribbonPageManager = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance();
    if (null !== ribbonPageManager) {
        ribbonPageManager.addPageComponent(MyProject.MyAudienceSetter.instance);
    }
}

MyProject.MyAudienceSetter.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        this.audienceIsSetChecked = false;
        this.audienceIsSet = 'Unknown';
    },
    getFocusedCommands: function () {
        return [];
    },
    buildCommands: function () {
        if (SP.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined(this.commands)) {
            this.commands = [];
            this.commands.push('MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Promote');
            this.commands.push('MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Demote');
        }

        return this.commands;
    },
    getGlobalCommands: function () {
        return this.buildCommands();
    },
    canHandleCommand: function (commandId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.commands.length; i++) {
            if (this.commands[i] === commandId) {
                if (!this.audienceIsSetChecked) {
                    this.checkIfAudienceIsSet();
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    },
    handleCommand: function (commandId, properties, sequence) {
        switch (commandId) {
            case 'MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Promote':
                break;
            case 'MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Demote':
                break;
        }
    },
    checkIfAudienceIsSet: function () {
        this.audienceIsSetChecked = true;

        var context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
        var item = list.getItemById(_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId);


        context.load(item, 'Include(Audience)');

        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
            var audience = item.get_item('Audience');
            RefreshCommandUI();
        }), Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
            alert(JSON.stringify(arguments));
        }));
    }
}

MyProject.MyAudienceSetter.registerClass('MyProject.MyAudienceSetter', CUI.Page.PageComponent);
MyProject.MyAudienceSetter.instance = new MyProject.MyAudienceSetter();

SP.SOD.notifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs('myaudienceSetter.js');
```

## and the loader :

```
/// <reference path="c:\Program Files\common Files\microsoft Shared\web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MicrosoftAjax.js" />
/// <reference path="c:\Program Files\common Files\microsoft Shared\web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\SP.debug.js" />
/// <reference path="c:\Program Files\common Files\microsoft Shared\web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\SP.Core.debug.js" />

SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var site = ctx.get_site();
        ctx.load(site);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
            var pageComponentScriptUrl = SP.Utilities.UrlBuilder.urlCombine(site.get_url(), "_layouts/15/MyProject/MyAudienceSetter.js");
            SP.SOD.registerSod('myaudienceSetter.js', pageComponentScriptUrl);
            SP.SOD.execute('myaudienceSetter.js', 'MyProject.MyAudienceSetter.initialize');
        }));
    }, "cui.js");
}, "sp.js");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not yet finished the implementation, but at least, I managed to make the `canHandleCommand` fire.

Actually, I have to implements the `Command` on the menu itself.

So I introduced a new command on the menu :

```
          <MRUSplitButton
            Id="SoSP.VDD.Intranet.Ribbon.PromoteNewToHomePage.PromoteNewToHomePage"
            Sequence="10"
            Alt="$Resources:core,ButPublish;"
            InitialItem="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Menu.Promote.Promote"
            MenuAlt="$Resources:core,ButPublish;"
            TemplateAlias="OneRow1"
            Command="MyProject.Ribbon.MyAudienceSetter.Split"
          >
```

I also ensure this command is returned by the `getGlobalCommands` function.